# i3 wm append_layout command

Tags: dependencies, window-managers

According to i3 documentation : [i3 append layout system](https://i3wm.org/docs/layout-saving.html#_append_layout_command) append_layout program should be available since i3 4.8

I don't have the append_layout i3 program in my path.

```
sudo find / -name "append_layout" | wc -l
0
```

my linux version is a Debian Jessie up to date

```
uname -a
Linux Sphinx 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.36-1+deb8u1 (2016-09-03) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

and

```
i3 --version
i3 version 4.8 (2014-06-15, branch "4.8") © 2009-2014 Michael Stapelberg and contributors
```

I don't mind where to find this program or if I missed a package setup on my linux.

Someone has an idea ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`append_layout` is an internal command of *i3* and not an external (command line) command.

In order to use it, you have to either use the `i3-msg` command line tool (or some other *i3* IPC library):

```
i3-msg append_layout /PATH/TO/LAYOUT.json
```

or you can bind it to a shortcut in your *i3* configuration (`~/.config/i3/config` or `~/.i3/config`):

```
bindsym Mod4+a append_layout /PATH/TO/LAYOUT.json
```

---

If you want to autoload a layout on *i3* startup, you can do so by running `i3-msg` via an `exec` configuration option:

```
exec --no-startup-id "i3-msg 'workspace 1; append_layout /PATH/TO/LAYOUT.json'"
```

Note the double quotes around the whole `i3-msg` command, which are needed to quote `;` from the *i3* configuration parser and the single quotes around the arguments to `i3-msg`, which are needed to quote `;` from the shell running the command.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works now for me.
But now I have to find how to run the programs into each tab as the loaded layout display black windows.

Comment: Just starting the corresponding application should be enough. If a new window matches the criteria on a placeholder container, it will be swallowed automatically.

Comment: You don't seem to need the outer level of quotes at all. `exec --no-startup-id i3-msg "workspace 1; append_layout ..."` works fine.